# Incrementing a number in a div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, increment

I'm very new to Javascript, so I assume this is a stupid mistake.

```
function upvote() {
    var score = parseInt(document.getElementById('voteScore').innerHTML);
    score = score++;
    document.getElementById('voteScore').innerHTML = score;
}
```

The div named "voteScore" contains the number 46 only (no HTML or anything). I am attempting to grab the string, convert it to an int, increment it and put it back in the div.

Comment: Well...That should walk as far as I can see

Comment: just how far is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`score++` increments `score`, you don't need to assign it back to `score`. Either remove the `score =` or change `score++` to `score+1`.

Comment: or `[...].innerHTML = score++;`

Comment: @OptimusCrime: won't that increment _after_ assignment? think you want `++score;` there.

Comment: That'd work, but personally I don't like using `++` or `--` in a statement like that, always alone to avoid possible confusion over execution order.

Comment: Wow, thank you. I have a Java background so this is no excuse :)